# The correct definition of ESRI geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase

Iet's see if i can explain my question correctly.

As the title says I'm looking for an definition of the databasetype that you create in ArcCatalog, file geodatabase and personal geodatabase.

The reason for this is that I'm looking for a list which types of databases that you can work directly with in ArcGIS Desktop Basic without extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/003n/003n00000007000000.htm) suffices.

> File geodatabases—Stored as folders in a file system. Each dataset is
>   held as a file that can scale up to 1 TB in size. The file geodatabase
>   is recommended over personal geodatabases.
>
> Personal geodatabases—All datasets are stored within a Microsoft
>   Access data file, which is limited in size to 2 GB.

Answer (score 0):

There is an added level of complication in there though as, for example, Basic can't edit in a geodatabase using relationship classes or utilise topology rules in the db